# Passing User identity through n-tier application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-of-work, n-tier-architecture

I have an MVC.Net application that is separated out into tiers containing Repositories, Business logic and front end services for AngularJS and MVC Controllers.

The repositories are currently stand alone and not wrapped in a unit of work pattern. This refactoring is going to take place.

I wanted to query with people what in their experience is the most efficient way to carry the current logged in user through the various tiers to enable security at the repository level.

At the moment I have a UserLogic class that maintains a reference to the current logged in user's Entity. This UserLogic class is then injected into controllers/business logic etc... But I suspect that's a fairly convoluted mechanism to use!

Comment: In what way is the user context going to be used for "security"?  For example, I worked on an app once where any database insert/update needed to be tagged with the user ID who performed it, and a convenient way to do that was to require the user context object when instantiating a unit of work object.

Comment: The application has a number of users who each own various other entities. I want to ensure that User A cannot access/modify User B's account. I want to do it in the Repo to remove the need for checking this in Controllers/Business logic multiple times.

Comment: If a repository can be used outside of a unit of work (which it clearly can before the intended refactoring, of course) then perhaps the same pattern can be applied in a wider sense, requiring a user context object in the construction of any given repository.  Then the repository operations can internally include `WHERE` clauses on that object's data transparently to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to have any given repository require a user context upon instantiation.  Something like this:

```
public class WidgetRepository
{
    private UserContext User { get; set; }

    public WidgetRepository(UserContext user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        // maybe also confirm that it's a *valid* user in some way?
        User = user;
    }

    // repository operations
}
```

You can employ as much "defensive programming" in that constructor as you like, I suppose.  Then in the repository operations you can filter queries based on that user.  Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Widget> Widgets
{
    get
    {
        return dbContext.Widgets.Where(w => w.Owner.Id == User.Id);
    }
}
```

This would filter all widgets by the user who owns them transparently to the application.

Keep in mind that there are trade-offs with this sort of thing.  Doing this could work really well in some scenarios, not so well in others.  If the DAL is transparently filtering data based on user context, then it could become quite difficult to perform system (non-user) operations or administrative (super-user) operations with the same DAL.  It's impossible to say if that's going to be a problem with my current knowledge of your system, this is just a heads-up on issues I've seen come up in the past.

Comment: There will be separate non-user repos available for administrative functionality. It's mainly part of a belt & braces approach. In your previous experience when did you attach the User to your UoW. I want to make sure the controllers remain testable and don't have a reliance on a HttpContext or similar to get the current user.

Comment: @BenFord: When my repositories all hang off of a unit of work object, I use the same pattern in my answer but only on that object instead of every repository object.  (Since in that design no repository could be instantiated without being part of a unit of work object.)  There's no reliance on HttpContext unless you create one.  My "user context" objects are custom (even if they're just wrappers for something framework-based) so they can be mocked. Otherwise, even aside from testing, having a static type reference to a web object in the DAL meant adding assembly references I didn't want there.